# Prestashop social bar newsleter color

Tags: html, css, prestashop

I would like to ask you for help. I just started using [prestashop](https://www.prestashop.com/en/) and I can not find the line of code responsible for the color of the newsletter/social bar <-above footer(please see the photo)

```
footer-container {
  background-color: #333; }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .footer-container {
      background: url(../img/footer-bg.png) repeat-x #1e1c49; }
}
```

I know that **`repeat-x #1e1c49;`** is responsible for the color of the footer, but not of the newsletter/social bar.

Also, do you know which line of code is responsible for the color of the text in the footer?(see photo) I think it shall be somewhere in global.css right?

I am sorry but i can not post image, i need at least 10 reputation to do this...

Thanks in advance for your attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

if we talk about default theme or something similar, in code that you provided

```
background: url(../img/footer-bg.png) repeat-x #1e1c49;
```

where

`../img/footer-bg.png repeat-x` the image (vertical line that repeated by x and with limited height ) responsible for the color of the bar

`#1e1c49` responsible for the color rest of the footer below.

it is basic CSS background property, detailed explnation you can find e.g. [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background), last example there is about your case.

Text color depends on what text exactly you mean, e.g. for the lists like Information, My account etc.

```
 .footer-container #footer a {
      color: #777777; 
  }
  .footer-container #footer a:hover {
        color: #fff; 
  }
```

all in `global.css`

Comment: Thank you, i managed to change to color of the footer. Nevertheless I still do not know how to change the color of the text.  I want to change the color of the following words:  My Company(address), email and call us now.

Comment: in Chrome: right click on element, Inspect element, on the right in Styles tab  you will see CSS rules, file and line number in this file